# Stubbing Carrierwave in RSpec to speed up tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, carrierwave

I'm saving an object to database in RSpec. This object has a Carrierwave field with its presence validation. I'm using `fixture_file_upload` for that field in a factory and it's very slow. I would like to stub Carrierwave file handling completely, but all solutions seem outdated and I can't get them to work.

My model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of   :image
  mount_uploader :image,  ProductMainImageUploader
end
```

My factory:

```
factory :product do
  name          { Faker::Product.product_name }
  slug          { name ? name.parameterize : nil }
  image         { 'sample_image.jpg' }
end
```

My spec:

```
describe Product do
  it "creates record" do
    ProductMainImageUploader.any_instance.stub(:store!)
    ProductMainImageUploader.any_instance.stub(:store_image!)
    product = create(:product)
  end
end
```

Results:

```
  1) Product creates record
     Failure/Error: product = create(:product, name: 'heyo')
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Image can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The stubs have no effect at all. I'm using Ruby 2.1.0. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try stubbing image

```
before do
  Product.stub(:image).and_return(ProductMainImageUploader.new)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error:(